# Print the numbers 1 to 100 using 5 semaphores and processes

Tags: c, linux, semaphore

I have an assignment to write a program in c language that will print to the shell the numbers 1 - 100. I must use 5 processes. The first one will print 1, 6, 11, 16... the second 2, 7, 12, 17... and so on.
I need to create 5 semaphores that will synchronize those processes.
The five semaphores need to be initialized with 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

Does that mean I need to use `semctl`?

Also, it is said that the process that prints 1 must be initialized with 4, the process that prints 2 - initialized with 3 and so on.

How do I perform this action?

Finally, it is said that before printing a number, I need to perform wait 4 times to reduce the semaphore value by 4, and after printing the number I need to use signal to increase the other semaphore values by 1.

I have tried so many ways to do so, but can't solve it. I don't understand the timing between those processes- how do I make each process use a certain semaphore? And how do I "go back" to that process later, and without creating child processes inside the child processes I already have?

This is the most that I could achieve:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void increaseallbutI(int i);
void cleanup();
int semid;
struct sembuf sops[1];

union semun
{
    int val;
    struct semid_ds * buff;
    unsigned short *array;
    struct seminfo *_buf;
};
union semun semarg;

void main()
{
    int i, j, k, status, num = 1;
    pid_t pid[5];

    semid=semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 5, 0600);

    for(i = 1; i < 17; i++)
    {
        signal(i, &cleanup);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        semarg.val = 4 - i;
        semctl(semid, i, SETVAL, semarg);
    }

    sops->sem_num = 0;
    sops->sem_flg = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if(fork()==0)
        {
            for(j = i + 1; j < 101; j += 5)
            {
                wait(&status);
                wait(&status);
                wait(&status);
                wait(&status);
                printf("%d\n", j);
                fflush(stdout);

                signal(i, &increaseallbutI);
            }
        }
    }
}

void cleanup()
{
    semctl ( semid , 0 , IPC_RMID , semarg );
    exit(1);
}

void increaseallbutI(int i)
{
    int k;
    for(k = 0; k < 5; k++)
    {
        if(k != i)
        {
            sops->sem_op = 1;
            sops->sem_num = k;
            semop ( semid , sops , 1 );
        }
    }
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Your program won't work as it is  since you're using the wait () function whose behavior is stopping the parent process until a child process returns. This means every process (parent and children) will wait for an exit which never arrives. What you actually want to use is a sem_wait function instead, which reduces the semaphore count by 1 and so you require 4 of them. Similarly, you need a sem_signal of some kind in order to increase the value of the semaphore. Did they tell you to implement your own semaphores, or are you allowed to use libraries?

Comment: First, thank you so much for answering.
Second, I think that I am allowed to use libraries.

Comment: So, instead of those `wait`s, I can call `sem_wait`?
What should I pass as an argument?
Do I need to create a `sem_t sem` and call `sem_init(&sem, 0, 0)`?

Comment: You must use sem_wait. If you're using posix semaphores then you should check on the documentation the correct syntax, then you should initialize 5 different semaphores and initialize them correctly (which means using sem_init with the correct values for the semaphore e.g. 4 for sem 1 and so on).

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your program is basically correct.

> So, instead of those `wait`s, I can call
>   `sem_wait`? What should I pass as an argument? Do I need to
>   create a `sem_t sem` and call `sem_init(&sem, 0, 0)`?

No, you and ThCP confused System V and POSIX semaphores. Since you are using System V semaphores (indeed better suited for your task), the function to be used for waiting is [`semop`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/semop.2.html).

> after printing the number I need to use signal to increase the other
>   semaphore values by 1.

By *signal*, certainly not the function `signal` is meant, but the increasing of the semaphore values which you correctly do in the function `increaseallbutI()` is called *signaling*.

Thus, the main loop and the end of the program could become:

```
    …
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (fork() == 0)
        {
            struct sembuf sop = { i, -4, };
            for (j = i + 1; j < 101; j += 5)
            {
                semop(semid, &sop, 1);
                printf("%d\n", j);
                increaseallbutI(i);
            }
            exit(0);    // child is done
        }
    }
    do ; while (wait(&status) > 0); // wait till all children are finished
    cleanup();
}
```

Don't forget to remove the `exit(1)` call in function `increaseallbutI()`!